# How to combine conan_toolchain.cmake and yocto OEToolchainConfig.cmake?

Tags: cmake, yocto, conan-2

I have a c++ project that I am cross compiling using a yocto sdk.
I'm starting to use conan 2.0 as a package manager to fetch third party libraries for my c++ project.

I created a conanfile.txt at the root of my project, using the cmake generators:

```
[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

I also created a *host* and *build* profiles:

- `conan_profile_cross_build`

```
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=12
os=Linux
```

- `conan_profile_cross_host`

```
[settings]
arch=armv8
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=12
os=Linux
```

To use it I run `conan install` and output the results into the build folder that will be used by cmake afterwards.

```bash
conan install /src --profile:build=conan_profile_cross_build "
            f"--profile:host=conan_profile_cross_host "
            f" --build=missing --output-folder=build
```

### The issue

To allow cmake to find the dependencies, you must call cmake with a toolchain file:
`cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake`

However when building with yocto sdk, you source the environment file:
`source environment-setup-armv8a-enchanted_tools-linux`, and it creates a cmake alias
that already sets a `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` to `OEToolchainConfig.cmake` which is somewhere inside the sdk.

cmake only allows one toolchain file so I can't use both of them.

I've seen in the [conan documentation](https://docs.conan.io/1/integrations/cross_platform/yocto.html#setting-up-a-yocto-sdk) that you should edit `OEToolchainConfig.cmake` which I did but it doesn't solve the problem that I can only choose one toolchain file.

### Question

How can I still use the sdk and allow cmake to find the conan provided packages ?
Maybe there is something to do in the host conan profile ?
Or is this workflow not a good idea and I should install the dependencies in yocto sdk directly ?
I am also compiling this project on native ubuntu linux desktop and here conan works great.
The idea is to easily test new dependencies before going through the hoops of integrating them into yocto and regenerating a whole sdk.

Comment: Note that the documentation you've linked to is for Conan 1, which might be easier to get working as documentation for yocto integration doesn't seem to be available for Conan 2 yet. See also https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/7285 and https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues/14343

Comment: Did you check: https://docs.conan.io/1/integrations/cross_platform/yocto.html ?

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM they've linked to that in their question and it's for Conan 1, not Conan 2

Comment: I did not catch that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Conan allows to include a second toolchain via a configuration option.
I added this in the `host` profile:

```
[conf]
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:user_toolchain="/home/yoctouser/sdk/sysroots/x86_64-etelsdk-linux/usr/share/cmake/OEToolchainConfig.cmake"]
```

I didn't need to edit the `OEToolchainConfig.cmake` file actually.